# RevisionableEntityBundleInterface not found

Tags: 8, entities, media

Getting

`bash
PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'Drupal\entity\Entity\RevisionableEntityBundleInterface' not found in web/modules/contrib/media_entity/src/MediaBundleInterface.php on line 11
Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.                                                                                 [error]
Error: Interface 'Drupal\entity\Entity\RevisionableEntityBundleInterface' not found in
web/modules/contrib/media_entity/src/MediaBundleInterface.php, line 11`

I found https://www.drupal.org/node/2722073, but we were already running media_entity-8.x-1.0 with entity-8.x-1.0-alpha3.

Brought in a big merge, imported config and now everything fails with the above error. Even though `core.extension.yml` has entity as enabled, when rebuilding the container, `cache_container` does not have entity in its `container.modules` array.

Is there a way to fix this without data loss?

Comment: Are you sure about your version? You don't have more than one entity module lying around? Try restarting apache, sometimes that gets negatively cached. Do you actually have the RevisionableEntityBundleInterface.php file in the src folder of the entity module?

Comment: One Entity module. alpha3. Checked and double checked that it has RevisionableEntityBundleInterface. Restarted the web server. Ended up just blatting the build is was not a production one. Spent far more time than needed on it without getting anywhere. Have a db dump, will try to investigate locally